# Does SQL have an equivalent function to datevalue() in dax?

Tags: sql-server, dax

In dax, there is a `datevalue()` function which changes my date/time to 12:00 AM for all dates.

Is there a SQL equivalent to this? I have a date column with various dates and times.

I want all times to read 12:00 AM. Thanks

Comment: `cast(thedatetime as date)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter he'd want: `cast(cast(thedatetime as date) as datetime)` to get the 12am back though.

Comment: @Tanner: i had that first but deleted it again from my comment because it's not clear what he wants. He can also use this `date`

Comment: thank you. The output is now 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000
Almost there :)

Comment: @Tanner: well, then he needs to tell us where he wants to show it. In C# for example the `date` is also mapped to `System.DateTime`. Displaying a `date`/`datetime` is a different topic. If he wants to convert it to `varchar` he needs to mention it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways. One is to convert your datetime to date. Another option is to do some date math,

```
select convert(date, getdate())
    , dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Date datetime = GetDate()

Select ActualDate = @Date
      ,Formatted  = format(cast(@Date as Date),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt')
```

**Returns**

```
ActualDate                Formatted
2017-03-08 10:18:47.683   2017-03-08 12:00:00 AM
```

I suspect you want the Formatted value